# My tomcat 8 home page is working but unable to run my projects

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have installed `tomcat 8` and configured in eclipse mars with `jdk 1.8`, and am getting tomcat succussfull home page while running, but it's showing error while running with my projects.

This problem happening with all my projects I'm getting home page but while running my projects its showing error like `"requested resource not found"`

error like

```
"HTTP Status 404 - /First/
type Status report
message /First/
description The requested resource is not available.


Apache Tomcat/8.0.41"
```

I did too much but unable to recover the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly map for ulrs to your servlers/controllers.

Mapping rules from Servlet specification:

- Map exact URL
- Map wildcard paths
- Map extensions
- Map to the default servlet

Please see the following url: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configureservlet.html